# Process the output of msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I am writing an app in C# that will call MSbuild.exe for a given solution file.

I use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to start msbuild.exe and fetch the output of that exe through its standard output stream.

I want to know the results - what errors occured, in which file and line etc... Is parsing the output string of MSbuild.exe the only way? Or are there ways to get the results in objects or arrays or something?

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild just outputs strings. I'm pretty you're going to have to direct the output to a file or files and parse that. At that point you can do what you like with it and load object collections or whatever.

Comment: Exactly what is "not text" about XML?  XMl makes for simpler parsing, but parsing nonetheless to accomplish what the OPis asking for.

Comment: "not text" ? XML ? Not sure where you get that from. My point is that you didnt correct the fact that the console output isnt really where it's at - you use /flp and the other logging options to make redirection and management of all that stuff irrelevant and just focus on the resulting XML (the standard logging wont emit XML to console anyway IIRC).

Comment: You're right, I should have mentioned the loggers directly. File-logged XML or redirected console output is still parsable text.  XML is *friendlier* to parsing, but still text.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild has a massive variety of logging options to suit your every need, from text to XML to cusotm ones. You'll also want to understand how you can subset outputs into multiple potentially overlapping files etc.

Start with `msbuild /?`

If you're doing anything remotely interesting, a copy of [Inside MSBuild 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735645248) will pay for itself in about 20 mins though - it has samples.